# How to write a Bash script for a C program that takes input multiple times?

Tags: c, bash, unix

So I have a C program that takes a command line argument, and does some stuff with it. After a short while, it re-prompts the user to for some standard input.

For example, a typical usage could look like this:

```
./prac1 4
4
Enter something else: _hello_
hello
```

My question is, how do I write a **bash script** that is able to re-enter more input (via stdin) in order to respond to the program's re-prompt once the program outputs
    Enter something else:
?

**I have this so far:**

```
cc=gcc
EXEC=prac1
SRC=prac1.c
input="4"

printValue=`./$EXEC $input`
if [ "$?" == '1' ];
then
    echo "Error"
    exit
fi
echo "printValue = $printValue"
```

**prac1** above refers to the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char* input[70];
    printf("%c\n", argv[1][0];
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Enter something else: ");
    fscanf(stdin, "%s", input);
    printf("%s\n", input);
}
```

The bash script calls the executable **prac1** with command line arg "4". When I run this script, after it executes with `` printValue=`./$EXEC $input` `` , I have to manually type something after the "Enter something else: " prompt. This is to be expected.

However, I am trying to figure out how to get bash to enter something automatically. What I mean by this is so that I do not have to enter it manually, myself.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. It lacks motivation and context, and you don't provide a full [MCVE]. We cannot guess what your `prac1.c` is supposed to do. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20805017) your question to improve it a lot. It seems to be some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Your current script has syntax errors; paste it on http://shellcheck.net/ for diagnostics.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document

Comment: Are you allowed to improve your `prac1.c`? Perhaps the features you want in your script are better and simpler to implement in that `prac1.c` file.

Comment: Perhaps you'd want to see [`expect(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/expect.1.html)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Probably, in this case, yes. Except I'm trying to learn how to do this for future projects where that won't be an option.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I don't mean to sound arrogant but you can just add "include <stdio.h>" to the top of the code provided and it is compilable/runable.

Comment: We still don't understand your actual goal. You look confused. What kind of applications do you want to code? Notice that terminal IO is *really* complex, much more that just using `scanf` or `fgets`.

Comment: Why can't you move more functionality into `prac1.c` and add some loop inside? And what is the overall purpose of your combined software (both `prac1.c` and your shell script)

Comment: Read about the [Unix philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy). What you want to achieve (which you didn't explain well enough) is probably against the Unix philosphy.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Because I am very confused. I have explained the question to the best of my ability and included every line of code I am referring to. Although, the others above understood perfectly well and they have lead me in the right direction.

Comment: Please explain the entire goal of your project (that is of your shell script and `prac1` combined). In general, you want to put more functionality in your C code and less in your shell script. I don't even understand why you are coding a shell script (since you could add more functionality in your C program). Maybe your entire project (we don't know what it is) could be written more simply as a *single* program (perhaps in Python or some other language, if C is difficult to you)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I am trying to learn bash scripting and quickly made up a C program to help me learn that. Although I have no idea why my motivations to learn something are important for constructing an answer. It would have been easier for both of us if you just answered the question like Antti Haapala, qrdl and tripleee kindly did.

Comment: Of course you want to learn, but I was asking of the motivation of your project. What is your project (your *real* `prac1.c` combined with your *actual* shell script) intended to do? We still don't know. My guess is that for your particular problem (which I don't know), avoiding a shell script and coding more into the `prac1` program is the wisest approach.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'll iterate something I said before. I'm trying to learn how to do this for future projects where I have a certain C program that meets a specification and I want to make a bash script that runs the program. The program, again, meets a specification and therefore I can not modify it to make the bash script easier to write. I guess another way to word it is If you want to cut an apple into pieces, you figure out how to cut the apple. You don't modify the apple so it doesn't need cutting.

Not sure why I continue to feed the trolls when I got some actual answers anyway..

Comment: Probably **`bash` is not suited for such tasks**. In those situations (where you want to drive a complex program that you are not allowed to change in some complex ways) you should not use `bash` but prefer some more complex scripting languages (perhaps Python) or some specific tool (sometimes it can be `make`, or `awk`, or your own specific C program, doing `fork`, `execve`, `waitpid`, `poll`, `pipe`, etc...)

Comment: You could do just this: `printValue=$(echo mystring | ./$EXEC $input)` for this simple case. Is the real use case this simple?

Comment: @hyde Thanks for the response, what I eventually had to do was use here-documents which was tripleee's answer, below.

Comment: Flushing an input stream is undefined behavior.  If it actually discards the input, it will defeat your intention.  Surely if the program is asking for more input, it should be the program that accepts it - re-running the program makes little sense.  Better to issue that prompt in the bash script.

Comment: @BenjaminPatch Echoing to pipe, or using here document, are basically the same thing. For one word, echoing is shorter.

Comment: Seems like you actually want to respond to the prompt. For tasks like that, use *expect* (or *pyexpect* or whatever) as already mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass all the input strings on standard input at once when you start running your program (e.g. as a [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document)); the OS buffering takes case of delivering them only when the recipient actually wants to read it.

```
printValue=$(./prac1 "$input"<<\____
first answer
Here's my answer to the second prompt.
If the script reads multiple lines of input
until EOF at any point, that of course will
consume all of the remaining here document.
____
)
```

Notice how we use `$(...)` syntax instead of the obsolescent `` `...` `` backtick syntax, and avoid putting into a variable a value which is only used once anyway *(viz.* the name of your executable).

As an aside, unless the exit code 1 is very specifically the only one you want to trap, just add `|| exit` at the end of the first line above (assuming your program prints a diagnostic when it quits with an error; or maybe refactor to a shell function `die` which prints an alert and *then* exits with the current exit code).

In your concrete example, because your program only needs one line of input, we can pass it as a string:

```
printValue=$(./prac1 "$input" <<<"something else")
```

or portably with

```
printValue=$(echo "something else" | ./prac1 "$input")
```

(the `<<<"here string"` syntax is Bash only.)

If your program is not well-behaved with line-buffered input, perhaps turn to [`expect`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/expect.1.html) for automating it; but realize that this also makes it harder for users in the future to write scripts around your tool. Perhaps you want to make it easier, maybe by allowing users to avoid interactive prompts (which are evil anyway) by passing in command-line options or a configuration file.

Comment: This is what ultimately solved my problem. Thank you for answering my question :)

Comment: How did "here documents" solved your question? They do not allow the script and `prac1` to run concurrently (as the initial form of your question suggested). In what sense *here documents* enable your `prac1` to take input *multiple* times?

Answer (score 1):

What you really want is unclear, and you don't explain the purpose of your script (so your question sounds like some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)) and what your `prac1` program is doing and should do.

So **read the [Bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/)**. Perhaps you want to use the `read` [bash builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html). You could also decide to give some data to your script thru [positional parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Positional-Parameters.html) or `getopts` [builtin](http://ttps://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.htm) or redirection from [here-documents](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Documents).

Maybe `bash` might not be the right tool for you. Probably you want some [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool (like [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [ninja](http://ninja-build.org/)). If your actual purpose is to rebuild some code when some file has been edited, it is the better way to go.

Look into several small [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) projects (e.g. on [github](http://github.com/), or from your Linux distribution) and study their source code for inspiration.

Perhaps moving more functionality into your `prac1.c` is the simplest way to achieve your (unstated) goals. That `prac1` might accept *several* program arguments. Read the [*Parsing Program Arguments*](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-Program-Arguments.html) chapter of [Glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) documentation.

If you want to code a script which interacts with a *running* process, it is complex. You could consider [coprocesses](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Coprocesses.html).

For completeness, I'll mention [`expect`](https://core.tcl.tk/expect/index) but I recommend not using it in your case (it would be simpler to improve `prac1`). Notice that `expect` is working at the terminal level, and Unix [terminal emulators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator), `tty`s and `pty`s are complex to understand (read [termios(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html), [pty(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pty.7.html), about [line discipline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_discipline), and [*The Tty Demystified*](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/)). If you really want to code terminal IO, consider using libraries like [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) or perhaps [readline](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html).

You could also learn more about Linux programming by reading a book like [*ALP*](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) (or something newer) and refer to the available [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). Notice in particular the ability to multiplex on input & output with e.g. [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html).

> how do I write a bash script that is able to re-enter more input

You should **avoid that situation**. If you really need to have a script driving some other program and have both the script and the program running together, you should consider some other approach (including writing the script in some other scripting language, e.g. Python, AWK, ...).

**The traditional usage of shell scripts is to drive inferior programs**, not to co-exist interactively with them (even if that could be possible with tricks like coprocesses; in more than 30 years of programming, I never used that).

When a feature is difficult to implement with a shell script, it is a symptom that your system should be organized differently. **The shell is *not* an answer to all problems** (sometimes it is simpler to use some other tool, more relevant to the task, or even to develop your C program driving other processes). As a rule of thumb I avoid too complex shell scripts. I might have some long (but conceptually simple, since sequential) shell scripts. I also have some programs (e.g. in `awk`, `m4`, C, or Python) generating (long) shell scripts (and [autoconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoconf) does that since a long time). But I avoid writing manually then maintaining myself complex shell scripts (and see them as a symptom of something wrongly designed).

To illustrate my point above: both `make` and `ninja` (and also [scons](https://scons.org/) and other build automation tools) are driving other programs. In principle, you could theoretically achieve their goals by writing a monstrous shell script doing the same. But in fact, nobody did that (and for good reason: the shell is *not* a universal tool in practice). So the lesson is: don't try to do with `bash` something it was not intended to do *easily* (and in my opinion that translates to: when your shell script becomes too complex, throw it away and use or write something else).

Read also about the [Unix philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy). Your combined script and C program smells badly against that Unix philosophy. Perhaps you should have a single program (probably coded in C, but much more complex that the `prac1.c` you show us), or perhaps you want a *simple* shell loop around some command running `prac1`.

The shell is a convenient tool (when used in *simple* scripts), but it is a poor programming language (and very difficult to statically analyze or to reason about; look for instance into the [CoLiS](https://www.irif.fr/~treinen/colis/) research project, and see Yann Regis-Gianas FOSDEM2018 talk on [*Parsing Posix [S]hell*](https://archive.fosdem.org/2018/schedule/event/code_parsing_posix_s_hell/)). **For complex enough tasks, you don't *want* to use [unix shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell)**, and you really want to use something better, and **you should throw away your shell script when it becomes unreadable or unmaintainable**.

PS. Your question makes implicitly the hypothesis that `bash` is suitable for most tasks. But this is not the case; on Linux you have many other scripting languages, e.g. [Python](http://python.org/), [`awk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/), [Ocaml](http://ocaml.org/), [Perl](https://www.perl.org/), [Io](https://iolanguage.org/), [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/), [`make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), [`ninja`](http://ninja-build.org/), [Lua](http://lua.org/), [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/), [PHP](http://php.net/), [Ocsigen](http://ocsigen.org/), [Haxe](https://haxe.org/), [`m4`](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/m4.html), ...), many of them more suitable than `bash`, at least in *some* niches. You'll better choose the tool suitable for your goals.

Comment: No, you still need to improve your question to make it some [MCVE]. Your question should include a reduced form of `prac1.c` and it still does not

Comment: And even with your new `prac1.c` I still don't understand your overall goal. Why do you organize your project in that way? Why can't you (for example) avoid needing any shell script and add more functionality in `prac1.c`. It seems that both `prac1` and your script are required to fulfull your (still unstated) goal, and I don't understand why you organized your project in two parts (the `prac1.c` and your shell script)